# How to implement package manager in fragment?

Tags: kotlin, fragment, package-managers

I try to implement package manager in Fragment, but it seems that in fragment we can't implement package manager. Here the code I use:

```
private fun takePhoto() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)

        createTempFile(application).also {
            val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this@CreateStoryActivity,
                "com.dicoding.bpaai.submission",
                it
            )
            currentPhotoPath = it.absolutePath
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
            launcherCamera.launch(intent)
        }
    }
```

Thank you for answering this.

[this is the code that used in activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEf87.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this line cause you problems:

`intent.resolveActivity(packageManager)`

try making it like this:

`intent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager)`

Comment: thank you, it work. but the application in the createTempFile line is error too.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. the createTempFile is function that add in utils kotlin file. Thank you for your answering..

Comment: sory, i don't know how. Please show me beacuse i new in stack overflow too.